# The dimension of the set of invertible matrices is $n^2$？

Tags: linear-algebra

While trying to read the following article,

> Keller J B. Multiple eigenvalues[J]. Linear Algebra & Its Applications, 2008, 429(8-9):2209-2220.

I came across the claim that "The dimensions of the set of matrices and the set of invertible matrices are both $n^2$."

I haven't been able to find a definition for this term,the dimension of the set of invertible matrices. While the set of invertible matrices is not a linear space,what does the dimension mean?Thank you very much!

Comment: "dimension" makes sense for a manifold.  In this case, the set of invertible matrices is an open subset of the set of all matrices.

Comment: @GEdgar I learned too little.Thank you very much!